# Create Custom Value in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form input that its value was generated by server.

```
    $getLastID = Model::select('id')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
//  echo $getLastID;

    $get_id=substr($getLastID, -2);
//  echo $no_urut;

    $prefix = date('Ym');

    $ordered_number = str_pad($get_id+1, 3,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
//  $no_urut++;

    $no_admin = $prefix.$ordered_number.'-01';
```

Which will generate 202006001-01 at first entry. Then, there is a problem. When the ID has reached 10++, it generate same value like first entry. It should be **202006010-01**, **202006011-01** and so on.

My question is, how to generate value like that in PHP?

Comment: str_pad($get_id+1, 3,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

Comment: Still didn't work @AllenBooTung

Comment: I don't understand what you want. https://paiza.io/projects/6-KaY9PBbkBMe4dhEhoJNg